# Вопрос по архитектуре скрипта

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

Приветствую!

Допустим, существует некий python3 скрипт запускаемый по cron каждую минуту и выполняющийся за 1-2 секунды и имеющий защиту от запуска копий скрипта. Грубо говоря, этот скрипт имеет 2 функции которые выполняются последовательно (то есть, каждую минуту по cron), однако фактически, выполнять каждую минуту нужно только одну функцию, вторая должна выполняться, ну например, каждый час. И я задался вопросом: А как правильнее это реализовать с точки зрения программирования, чтоб было не очень трудозатратно и не очень костыльно?

Вот несколько примеров решения, которые я рассматриваю:

1. `if time.strftime("%M") == '31': print("hello!")` Дописываем в скрипт условие, и получаем выполнение каждый час. Это, на мой взгляд, самый лёгкий вариант, но какой-то он костыльный...
2. Переписать скрипт на использование ключей/аргументов, типа каждуюу минуту запускаем `/usr/local/sbin/my_scrit.py --funk_one` и раз в час `/usr/local/sbin/my_scrit.py --funk_two` - этот вариант мне нравится больше, но тут мне придётся переписывать логику защиты от запуска повторных копий. Сейчас она реализована так:

   ```
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       fp = open(os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), '{}.lock'.format(os.path.basename(__file__))), 'w')

       try:
           fcntl.lockf(fp, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
       except IOError:
           print("My another instance already running. Do nothing")
           sys.exit(0)
   ```
3. Создавать какой-нибудь stat-файл и на сновании его содержимого, либо времени его создания - запускать вторую функцию.
4. Демонизировать скрипт при помощи, например, supervisorctl - но это долго и трудозатратно.

Comment: второй способ, конечно... логику защиты поменять будет едва ли ни быстрее, чем описывать всё это здесь =)) 1 и 3 — грубые костыли, 4 — вариант неплохой, но если делать по-простому получится ещё один костылик, запуск которого похоронен в недрах systemd (или ещё-какой-нибудь системы запуска), а если делать полноценный демон, то, сам понимаешь, что это абсолютный беспощадный перебор...

Comment: Лично я не люблю крон и делал бы вариант 4

Comment: использовал бы крон или supervisorctl.

Comment: демоны на системд пишутся за пару минут.